# BSOD In Windows 7: BAD_POOL_HEADER error after standby, maybe SSD related?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, ssd, power-supply, bsod

Sometimes (not always) when I raise my computer from standby (not hybrid mode), I get BSOD (after a bit, around 30 seconds). This problem exists since when I bought it, around 1 year ago.

I would like to know if there is some solution. I think that the problem is SSD related, but maybe I'm wrong because I've 2-3 issues.

My configuration is this:

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- OCZ Revodrive (X1) on PCI Express [**SSD**]
- Asus Rampage III Extreme [**Motherboard**]
- Nvidia Geforce 560 ti (gainward) [**Graphic card**]
- Corsair dominator 6GB (3 slots) [**RAM**]
- Corsair Professional Series HX850 850W 80Plus [**Power supplier**]
- i7-950 [**Processor**]
- 2 Screens (1 on DVI and other on PC cable)

I'm using the SSD as a RAM backup if I exceed my 6GB (only 2GB as suggested on OCZ website); but I think I never reached that limit (I have a G19 and I track my memory consumption on it's screen, and I really never filled up my **physical** memory) so maybe that's not the problem. Could it be just an incompatibility issue related to the fact that is on PCI-Express? Maybe Windows have some problems with it even with drivers.

The second thing that this may be created from is my graphic card, infact I got a lot of times the message *"285.xx" driver has stopped working and has been restarted*. While this doesn't happen while I play under heavy load (battlefield 3/skyrim/other heavy games), it happens sometimes when simply using Windows, roaming around my desktop. Also recently Windows stopped to recognize my main screen, to fix it just needed to press *Detect* under resolution settings, but it's worth a notice.

The third and last thing that this problem may be created from is my power supplier:

When I shutdown my computer if it has been under heavy load it makes a silent noise like  whistle which can't be heared if there are other noise, but when you are going to sleep, you can definitely hear it and it's quite boring. The only solution I've found to this is detach my computer from electric supply (by pressing the button 0/1 behind my power supplier).

Maybe the graphic card problem is directly connected with the power supply issue (it doesn't send enough energy?), or maybe the power supply is not working well because the graphic card asks for energy even when computer is shutting down. I really don't know.

That being said, I would like to solve my BSOD problem by understand which is the problem, doesn't matter changing my hardware because I still have warranty, but is boring having a good computer with problems.

**Edit 1:**

BSOD Minidump:

> 011212-11419-01.dmp   12/01/2012
>   06:14:39  BAD_POOL_HEADER 0x00000019  00000000`00000003   fffff8a0`1625a220   59e5cce1`ae26b91c   fffff8a0`1625a220   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+7cc40  NT
>   Kernel & System   Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft
>   Corporation   6.1.7601.17640
>   (win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506) x64 ntoskrnl.exe+7cc40                  C:\Windows\Minidump\011212-11419-01.dmp 8   15  7601    288.248

Human readable version:

[image: Minidump image]

**Edit 2:**
I should also point out that the thing about graphic drivers that stopped working is happen more frequently this period, maybe something is "getting worser".

**Edit 3:**
I updated all drivers/bios of the motherboard and so on. It looks like the problem is persisting.

**Edit 4:**
Seems like the graphic card problem is not connected with this one, I fixed with [this topic](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=213744) on nvidia forums

**Edit 5:**
It's long time that the problem doesn't show up, I'm not sure it is fixed for some reason (maybe connected with graphic driver and power management?) I'll let you know. Thanks for all help

Comment: just wanted to make sure that you do not turn the PSU switch after you put machine into sleep, do you?

Comment: By "RAM backup" did you mean pagefile?

Comment: You should check your SSD firmware, too. I have a SSD from OCZ, too and I had a lot of problems at the beginning. Then I've updated to the latest firmware and everything was fine.

Comment: Ok I'm answering to everyone: @user377178 **No**, I do it only when I completely shutdown my computer, because in that case the noise is tronger. cmorse: Yes sorry, I meant exactly the pagefile. Feroc: I'll try it tomorrow and tell you results, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the graphic card problem, after it has been fixed, fixed bad pool header problem too.

It's connected with a energy supply issue with the graphic card. Infact there is a bug with latest nvidia drivers (only with 560 ti) that tweak with energy supply in some way when clock is low, making the system unstable.

Thanks for anyone, hopefully they will fix the bug in next driver release.

Comment: The question is old but I want still confirm this, seems that NVIDIA is failing hard on a lot of drivers, I have to keep up to date with beta drivers to avoid issues. This latest version however is not giving me trouble.

Answer (score 3):

`BAD_POOL_HEADER` BSOD almost always indicates a faulty software (e.g. a device driver bug), rather than a faulty hardware. What it says is that an essential internal Windows data structure has been corrupted, and Windows cannot continue. If the BSOD is inconsistent (e.g. you're getting a different code each time), then the code itself is not indicative, obviously.

One needs to use programming tools (kernel debugger, etc.) to analyze the problem and fee which driver is at fault, and this is time-consuming and the success is not guaranteed.

One other thing you can do is to test your memory with [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/), since faulty memory *might* be the cause of this kind of BSOD (rare).

My conclusion: Most probably not SSD-related in any way, try updating your drivers (motherboard, graphic card, etc.) and see if it helps.

Comment: I updated all drivers of my motherboard/graphic card (bios of motherboard too), but the problem is persisting, I must think my graphic card has some problems

Answer (score 1):

While it is probably a driver or memory issue, looking at ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557389%28VS.85%29.aspx ) indicates that params 2,3,and 4 in your screencap should be identical.

It is very unusual, but possible, that you have a rootkit or other malware that is inserting something into the pool. It may only cause an issue when resuming the system.

Doesn't hurt to check.

Google terms: "kernel pool exploit"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but even with those google terms I find articles on how hacking the problem, not how to solve it.
As I can read by the way this could be a driver issue too.

Comment: For completeness, the way to solve this problem *if you had it* would be by removing the rootkit or malware.

Comment: I searched with my antivirus and my anti malware software (big scan), and with a rescue cd (that runs from cd) and I couldn't find anything on my computer. If you can suggest some software I can still look with it. But I don't think it was a malware problem now, expecially because energy supply issues can corrupt bits in some way

Comment: Thanks for following my question, I tested a lot of times the standby and it seems completely ok now. Seems nvidia bugged a lot my graphic card with that driver, everything it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Tech talk: Dell Inspiron 6400 , ATI Mobility Radeon X1400, Problem start with plan basics,
1.blue screen of death, Make sure you have enough space for air flow to and from by pass port and fan, on bottom side.
If there is a over heating issue, have a tech do some maintenance cleaning, ( clean off heat sink cooler ), so air can flow through correctly.

One needs to use programming tools (kernel debugger, etc.) to analyze the problem and figure out which driver is at fault. This is very time-consuming and success is not guaranteed (or even probably in many cases, depending on the skill level of the debugger).

One other thing you can do is to test your memory with [Passmark](http://www.passmark.com/), since faulty memory might be the cause of this kind of BSOD (though it is rare).

My conclusion: Most probably not SSD-related in any way, try updating your drivers (motherboard, graphic card, etc.) and see if it helps.

Comment: Did you tried updating to BETA drivers? I solved my issue with that (now the beta are standard and infact everything is ok). The issue was a bug with power supply to the graphic card in the nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This error showed up about 15 seconds after plugging in an external hard drive. Long story short, it was caused by a bad Macrium Pro update from a few days ago.

Yesterday's release notes from Macrium (they make backup software):

> Bug fixes and Improvements v8.1.7367 - 7th February 2023
>
> Changed Block Tracker We've resolved a rare BAD_POOL_HEADER exception
> caused by an I/O error raised when CBT read a highly fragmented NTFS
> Master File table (MFT).

Applying the patch fixed the problem.